# Error: No result rowset is associated with the execution of this query

Tags: sql-server, ssis, runtime-error, constraints

Query which should be stored as variable in "Execute SQL Task":

```
Use [Reporting]
Go

DECLARE 
@current_month DATETIME, 
@current_year DATETIME, 
@current_year_final AS INT, 
@previous_period_final VARCHAR(2),
@test_period AS VARCHAR (2),
@previous_period_final_2 VARCHAR(2)

SET @current_month = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),0)
SET @current_year = DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()),0)
SET @current_year_final = CASE WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) = '01' THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@current_year,112),4)-1 ELSE LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@current_year,112),4) END
SET @previous_period_final = CASE
 WHEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 BETWEEN 10 AND 11 THEN  CAST(CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 AS VARCHAR)  -- Type Varchar
 WHEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),3),1) AS INT) - 1 BETWEEN 1  AND 8  THEN '0' + CAST(CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),3),1) AS INT) - 1 AS VARCHAR)
 WHEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 = 9 THEN '09'
 WHEN      LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) = '01'          THEN '12'
 ELSE 'Invalid formula' END
SET @previous_period_final_2 = CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 

-- ### Returns: 
--    1 = 'identical' = row numbers match
--    0 = 'mis-matched' = row numbers do not match
select sum(rows_identical) as rows from

(
select CAST(CAST(case when count_rows_raw = count_rows_facts then 1 else 0 end as bit)as int) as rows_identical 
--,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CAST(CAST(case when count_rows_raw = count_rows_facts then 1 else 0 end as bit)as int),'BaseType') -- ### EXCELLENT WAY TO RETRIEVE DATATYPE ###
from
(
 select
 (
  select SUM(#rows_facts) as #rows_facts from 
  (            
   select COUNT(ID) as #rows_facts, 'finalized_entries_facts_table' as type from facts_reporting  
 where YearMonthID in (select YearMonthID from dim_year_month as yyMM  
        where yyMM.YearMonth = CAST(@current_year_final AS Varchar)+'_'+CAST(@previous_period_final AS Varchar))
 and SourceID IN (select SourceID from dbo.dim_source where Source = 'Unlocks')

union

   select COUNT(ID) as #rows_facts, 'missing_entries_facts_table' as type from missing_ids_Unlocks_raw 
 where YearMonthID in (select YearMonthID from dim_year_month as yyMM  
        where yyMM.YearMonth = CAST(@current_year_final AS Varchar)+'_'+CAST(@previous_period_final AS Varchar))
 and SourceID IN (select SourceID from dbo.dim_source where Source = 'Unlocks')         
  ) as rows
 ) as count_rows_facts,
 (
SELECT count(*)as #rows_raw from UnlocksRawCSV_table as raw
Where Year_Month_inserted = CAST(@current_year_final AS Varchar) + '_' + @previous_period_final
 ) as count_rows_raw
)
as row_checks
)
as count_check 
--where rows_identical <> 0
```

Variable definition and Result Set mapping in SSIS:
[image]

In the Execute SQL Task I have selected "Result Set = Single row". I have also tried "None". I have put a post-execute Breakpoint on the Execute SQL Task and get this:

[image]

== Why am I getting a 0 as value in SSIS while I am getting a 1 if I execute this query (see above) in SQL Server directly?

The precedence constraint in the subsequent task look like this:

[image]

EDIT 1: Changing this expression to `@RowCheck == 0` does not change anything as the task still fails on execution with the same error:

> Error: No result rowset is associated with the execution of this query

EDIT: 2: Changing the Value in the Precedence Constraint Editor from "Success" to "Failure" works but I don't understand why the task itself fails and why it generates the above mentioned error message? However, despite proceeding with the package the value displayed for variable RowCheck does not make any sense as it is always zero, regardless of that the Query returns...

EDIT 3: Screen of General Tab for Execute SQL Statement (I have also tried with "Single Row" and above mentioned Result Set Mapping:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the top of your SQL in the Execute SQL Task, it could be that the row counts are interfering with the variable assignment, leading it to not be assigned as 1.

Comment: Yeah, I did that but this did not help unfortunately. I am still always getting a 0 as variable value.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the `General` tab of your Execute SQL Task properties?   Also have you tried using Profiler to verify that the SQL being executed by the package is what you expect?   and returns the results you expect?

Comment: @TabAlleman I have posted a picture above of the respective tab. Not sure what Profiler you mean. Where can I find it? I just executed the SQL in SQL Server Studio and there I am getting the expected results/values

Comment: Try ending each of the statements in your SQL script with a semi-colon.  And change ResultSet back to "Single Row".  And google `SQL PROFILER TUTORIAL` to see what it is and how it works.   What happens with your current query when you click `Parse Query`?

Comment: @TabAlleman I did all of that but with no success. I was setting up a new very simple package where I define an Int variable and set value to `1` and then use this value in the precedence constraint setting `single row` in the SQL task. And still, either I get `"no results are associated..."` or the package is executed (choosing `None` as ResultSet) but the variable always retains 0 as value... Do you maybe have such a sample package with a precedence constraint? I have no idea what is going wrong here...

Comment: Could it have to do something with the scope of the variable?

Comment: You didn't answer:  what happens when you click Parse Query?   Your variable should be scoped at the package level.   If it is not, then please make it so and try again.

Comment: It says "The query parsed correctly" but the result remains the same with a 0 value variabel

Comment: @TabAlleman Is there maybe an alternate way to achieve the same result? All I want is the query to continue with the next task if the result of the query is 1 (@RowCheck == 1)  or stop and send mail if the result is other than 1.

Comment: Well you could use `@RowCheck != 1` for the other path, but I don't think that will help because the error you are getting indicates it happens before the precedence constraint is evaluated.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yeah, this didn't help as my variable is not getting any other value than 0 (= start value) which I do not understand at all. Even with the most simplest SQL such as `Select cast(5 as int)` in the SQL the value does not change to 5!!! Why?

Comment: In the `Result Set` tab of the Execute SQL Task, try using '0' for the result name, instead of the expected column name.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks, I did that but it didn't change anything. I have tried all combinations for Result Set, Datatypes, Names etc... I was so desperate that I created a new package with nothing in it and used a String variable with "Yes" and "No" as constraints. This worked. I then deleted the variable in my existing package and created a new one and did exactly the same as I did before but now it worked... I am happy and confused altogether... any explanation for that?

Comment: There could have been a lot of things you missed in your testing, that can only be caught while it's happening.   Or sometimes packages, or objects in packages, just seem to get corrupted, and destroying and re-creating them is the only way to fix them.

Comment: @TabAlleman Ok, then my take away is: If you can't fix it by applying reasonable steps then break it and re-create :) Thanks for your support!